# k-ary Trees Induction Proof

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm getting stumped by this problem:

You have a tree with every internal node having k children, with k >= 2.
What is the maximum number of nodes that such a tree can have, if its depth is d? Prove your
answer by induction on d.

So I realize that if k was 2, the geometric series would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 8...+2^n, but I can't figure out how to include depth and how to prove it inductively.

Comment: Try writing the series as 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of items in a full k-ary tree of n levels is `(k^n - 1)/(k - 1)`.

A binary tree of 5 levels, for example, has 31 nodes (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16). Or:

```
(2^5 - 1)/(2 - 1) = 31/1 = 31
```

A 4-ary tree of 4 levels has 85 nodes (1 + 4 + 16 + 64)

```
(4^4 - 1)/(4 - 1) = 256/3 = 85
```

If you write out a few of those for different values of `k`, you should be able to derive the inductive proof.